# How to limit only iPhone 5s can download my app

Tags: ios7, xcode5, iphone-5, info.plist, apple-m7

I just want my app can be downloaded to iPhone 5s, because of using M7 processor,which can not run on other iPhones.

Previously we have "Required device capabilities" in the Info.plist, for this case, what is the item to add ? Any simple way to achieve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I require an iPhone 5S for my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967996/can-i-require-an-iphone-5s-for-my-app)