# Which iOS devices support CMStepCounter?

Tags: ios7, core-motion, apple-m7

Apple added step count support with the M7 in the new iPhone 5s. This is the documentation on isStepCountingAvailable

> isStepCountingAvailable Returns a Boolean indicating whether
>   step-counting support is available on the current device.
>
> - (BOOL)isStepCountingAvailable Return Value YES if step-counting support is available or NO if it is not.
>
> Discussion Step-counting support is not available on all iOS devices.
>   Use this method to determine if support is available on the current
>   device.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 7.0 and later. Declared In
>   CMStepCounter#

When I run:

`BOOL isUsersHardwareCompatibleWithPedometerApp = [CMStepCounter isStepCountingAvailable];`

on my 5s isUsersHardwareCompatibleWithPedometerApp's value is `YES`.

Which devices will return YES for Core Motion's CMStepCounter class method `+ isStepCountingAvailable`? Also can I restrict devices which return `NO` from downloading my app in the AppStore? Or is there a good proxy for restricting users from downloading my app such as the front facing camera being a good proxy for determining if the user has at least 512mb of ram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a device to test with but @_DavidSmith, creator of the popular Pedometer++ app has determined that the new iPad Air/rMini don't give step data.

> After some investigation the iPad Air/rMini look to support activity
>   categorization but not step counting w/ its M7. Which makes sense to
>   me

https://twitter.com/_DavidSmith/status/404252937821900801

Thus so far the iPhone 5s is the only device that supports step data.

Answer (score 2):

Currently (Nov 2013), only the iPhone 5S, the iPad Air and iPad mini with retina display have the M7 coprocessor, which is required for step counting. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19467467/983912), there is no way currently to restrict devices based on M7 availability.

Comment: http://www.apple.com/ipad-air/specs/ says differently. "A7 chip with 64-bit architecture and M7 motion coprocessor"

Comment: Thats what I thought at first but I don't think we can make the assumption that just because a device has an M7 that it can count steps. https://twitter.com/_DavidSmith/status/404252937821900801

Comment: Hmm makes sense in a way, but still weird why Apple would hide the data. Could be of privacy concerns.

Comment: Well Apple does make the user give permission to see 'location data' but in this case maybe Apple thinks that step data isn't useful or interesting on an iPad.