# Step Counting on iPads

Tags: ipad, counting, motion

I know that iPad Air 2 has M8 motion co processor, but the CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable() always return false on this device. Does that mean the step counting is not available? On which iPads step counting is available? I appreciate any help.

Comment: You want to carry around an iPad and count steps?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166556/which-ios-devices-support-cmstepcounter

Comment: Not really @Rick S, but I have an iPhone app for app store and they guidelines say it should run on iPad too.

Comment: I have seen that @mazeem, but I am not sure that is also true for iPad Air 2. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @RickS [why not?](http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/d6/fe/64/d6fe646f69463c0626a0ea106a85ce34.jpg)

Comment: @rickster Take it up with Apple, I don't make the rules.